# jboss/Java EE - authentification role

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'd like to develop an application based on jboss (wildfly) authentication and I know that Jboss gives a login.html file. Do I have to use this file in order to use role authentification functionality ?
Indeed the login.html is linked to some jboss files but I'd like to do ohter things : for example I could check if the user who is trying to log in is in my database.

Can I use my own jsp file (in order to use my servlets to access my database) and also have the authentification part ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use your own JSP file.

Take a look at the JBoss JAAS examples.